# Active Directory Domain passphrases with white spaces

Tags: samba, domain

A `corporate Active Directory domain` is configured to require `passphrases` instead of `single passwords`. Requirements include capital letters and numbers\special characters to be included. Examples would be:

> *How now brown cow?*
>
> *Live long and prosper!*

What is the proper syntax to use for these `white-spaced passphrases` when connecting to an `smb share` on that domain, from a linux smb client?

Comment: Tell us (by updating the question) what you have tried, and what happened.

Comment: I've seen this, too. Spaces in smb share names require \040 to be placed, in order to work. So a shared smb dir shared as *\\\server\My Data* requires *\\\server\My\040Data* to work. Will that work as well for passphrases? Problem is **password=One Two Three Four!** gets passed as **password=One** ... and fails.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see a problem with whitespace in passwords, similar to the passphrases you have described. It would help if you explained what issues you are seeing, but in the meantime here is my offering.

1. I've checked a `credentials` file used in a `mount` command:

   ```
   mount mount -t cifs -o credentials=/tmp/credentials //localhost/stuff /mnt/stuff

   cat /tmp/credentials
   username=joe
   password=d r
   domain=workgroup
   ```
2. I've checked use of `password` directly in a `mount` command (why anyone would do this is a mystery to me, though):

   ```
   mount -t cifs -o 'username=joe,domain=workgroup,password=d r' //localhost/stuff /mnt/stuff
   ```

   Notice here that because the password contains whitespace that will be parsed by the shell, standard quoting rules apply and it must be single-quoted.
3. I've checked `smbclient` directly:

   ```
   smbclient --user joe --command 'dir' //localhost/stuff 'd r'
   Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.5.12-Debian]
     .                                   D        0  Tue Oct  4 21:56:16 2016
     ..                                  D        0  Tue Oct  4 21:56:16 2016

                   7194072 blocks of size 1024. 2644964 blocks available
   ```

Admittedly, these are all connecting to `localhost` with Samba running in `security = USER`, but if you need me to - and I can get time - I'll also check on a full AD domain environment.